# Push Pull Classes intermidiate

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I would like to move a sidebar to the left of the layout.

However, I would also like to keep the order of the first 3 elements first in the HTML and then have the sidebar, as the 4th element, moved to the left and aligned to the top of the page.

This is a little academic and would probably be purely for SEO purposes.

Below I am unsung foundations markup.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-9 push-3 columns"> main content </div>
<div class="small-9  push-3 columns"> main content </div>
<div class="small-9  push-3 columns"> main content </div>
<div class="small-3 pull-9 columns end" > left sidebar </div> 
</div>
```

Currently, I have 2 rows with 3 columns of empty space, then the side bar on the left in line with the 3rd row. I though the "end" attribute would float it to the left and up but....

Anyone who can enlighten me as to the solution will have my thanks.

CSS

```
[class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child {
 float: right; }

 .row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 62.5rem; }

.columns {
position: relative;
padding-left: 0.9375rem;
padding-right: 0.9375rem;
float: left; }

.small-9 {
width: 75%; }
.small-3 {
width: 25%; }

@media only screen {
 .small-push-0 {
   position: relative;
   left: 0%;
   right: auto; }

 .small-pull-0 {
   position: relative;
   right: 0%;
   left: auto; }
}


[class*="column"] + [class*="column"].end {
  float: left; }
```

Cheers,
Justin

Comment: _the end_ attribute? That is just a CSS class so it will not do anything unless you added some (the correct) styling to it.

Comment: could you also provide us with some css ? presumably your `end` class has some `float` or `positions` attributes to it? also, it's useful to show us what you tried so we can start from there .

Comment: Thanks, I'm v.new to this so bear with me. I have pulled all the relevant CSS I think should apply. This is from the foundations 5 framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the `float: left;` from your `columns` class with `display: inline;`, so that the columns only display as one next to the other and don't get pulled in any direction, and you can add css for your `end` class to drag the final column to the left

The `HTML` is the same as yours, but the `CSS` will look like this

```
.columns {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    display: inline;
}

.end {
    float: left;
}
```

Everything else in your `CSS` stays the same as it was.

Here's a Jsfiddle of the end result: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJamL/)

---

I just realized that my code aligns all the div's on the same row, while your code aligned all of the one under the other. From the question it's not very clear (to me at least) if you want the first 3 div's to be one next to the other (as I presume from your `CSS` code), or the last one to the left and the first 3 to the right of the last one and one under the other. If you are looking for a solution to the second situation I presented, please add a comment so I can change my code.

---

**Update**

After looking into the explained request, I came up with this changes

**CSS** code required:

```
.arange_to_left {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
.arange_to_right {
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
}
.columns {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-width: 62.5rem;
}
```

**HTML** code required (and simplified):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="arange_to_right">
        <div class="small-9 push-3 columns">1. Something</div>
        <div class="small-9  push-3 columns">2. Something else</div>
        <div class="small-9  push-3 columns">3. Anything else</div>
    </div>
    <div class="arange_to_left small-3 pull-9 columns">SIDE BAR</div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle to how it will look: [result](http://jsfiddle.net/fJamL/9/)

Please note that I left a little room between the left and right div. This is not required but I left it to compensate for possible borders, margins and padding that you might want to add. Obviously you can change the `%` of the left and right div to what you want / need.

Also, this will not expand your `row` div to surround the other divs as they are floated. I have set up [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fJamL/7/) fiddle to show how you can expand the row around it's content. (this fiddle also has the full demo text and borders drawn)

For this last example I did add the CSS for `end` and created an empty div at the end of `row` (but still inside it)

```
.end {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: @user3779594 please check my answer's update and let me know (using your fiddle as an example) on how it should look

Comment: Thanks! I have added a border to better visualise the idea and added some Lorem ipsum text.The way I would wish to see it would be that the sidebar should align top left spanning 3 columns, then to the right I would like 3 "block"  level (relatively speaking) content elements spanning 9column that "float" to the right of the sidebar. I hope that makes sense? I have updated the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fJamL/5/

Comment: It would be the second in your update. Getting to grips with this website as well :/

Comment: @user3779594 The best solution for that would be to change the HTML a little bit, not the CSS, so that the first 3 div's would be in a holder and the last one separate, so you can just float the 2 to the left and to the right as desired.

Comment: I think you are right, but it somehow does not work for me. Can you help alter the original fiddle for the solution?

Comment: @user3779594 check out the full update to see how you could try to make it work

Comment: Yes, this code you added worked a treat! You have the solution. thx

Answer (score 0):

So I might have found a solution to what you want, maybe. It's all done with straight `css` and `html`. Are you wanting one left-side-bar or one left-side-bar per row? The per row example is first. The one to the left is second.

per row:
http://jsfiddle.net/75WA9/

one to the left:
http://jsfiddle.net/UPpDS/

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but in the end for the minimal code change I chose the answer above. Good work though.